# Finding smallest number at specific column and then returning that row

Tags: python, list

Say if i have the table data = `[[1, 2, 0.5], [2, 5, 0.49]]` . How could i create a function that finds the smallest element at the 3rd column out of the two rows and then returns the row that that number is in?

Eg. since the smallest number in the 3rd column is 0.49 out of the two rows. I want the function to return `[2, 5, 0.49]`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`min()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) with a `key` that compares the third elements of the lists.

```
min(data, key=lambda l: l[2])
```

Comment: Beat me by a second :)

Answer (score 0):

How about like this:

```
td = [[1, 2, 0.5], [2, 5, 0.49]]

col = 2 # third column

min_row = td[0] # initialze to something
for row in td:
    if row[col] < min_row[col]:
        min_row = row

print(min_row)
```